Why does pivot table show weird totals?
I have a filtered pivot table with multiple fields in the 'rows' section.
When you calculate the total of the numbers in the rows, I get a totally different total than what is shown as total in the field above. I have seen this multiple times now and I do not understand why this happens.
Below is the pivot table:

As you can see, the total for 'Zuid-Holland' (62) is not even near what the total should be (at least 62+11+9+7, this field is filtered for 'top 4').
I can't understand why it says 62.

Another example. The total of selected cells is 558. but the total for Hoek van Holland says 482.

It would help to see your data ...

I know but I can't share that data because of classification.

Try to create a minimal example with fake data that reproduces your issue ... otherwise how should we be able to help you?

You already did by asking for the data. I found the explanation. The data shows reasons for refusal. And one proces can have multiple reasons. The pivot counts distinct processnumbers so for Zuid-Holland it counts how many distinct proces numbers are found. While 1 level lower, It counts the same but for each individual reason for refusal.

Look at your source data, do you have a column with totals?  This may be a different column pulling in.
